# What is the default DPI when using puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, dpi

When using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) without changing any settings, what is the default Dots per inch (DPI) when saving a PDF?

Comment: Thanks @JK, is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the default it 96dpi.

From some testing and trying to render a design at 72dpi, it's clear that the output is out by a factor of 1.33333.

It doesn't seem there is a way to configure this however.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "scale" option to 1.333 ?